# How to install Tomcat8 tar.gz on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, linux-kernel, tomcat8

JDK is already installed there.I have downloaded the apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar.gz in /opt/tomcat. I want their folder structure webapps and all.

Executed the command `/path/tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar.gz`, but now also there is tar file present. How do I get folders inside tomcat?

Comment: That error tells you that the file name you typed is incorrect. Check if you have a space after `tar` in the file name

Comment: I copied it from name of file itself

Comment: `apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory` means that the must have been `tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar` or something like `tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar .gz`. You only have to look close enough...

Comment: it is apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done:

```
sudo tar xvzf /opt/file_path/apache-tomcat-7.0.54.tar.gz -C /opt/extracted_folder_path --strip components=1--
```

It will extract tar file into extracted_folder_path.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

tar (child): **apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory**

It's means that the file name is incorrect or is not on the directory you are.

Try this
tar xzvf /PATH_OF_THE_FILE/apache-tomcat-8.5.29.tar.gz

also check the name of the file you typed.

Answer (score 0):

when you extract the tar.gz file, you should see an output like this:

```
...... (lot of information)
apache-tomcat-8.5.29/bin/configtest.sh
apache-tomcat-8.5.29/bin/daemon.sh
apache-tomcat-8.5.29/bin/digest.sh
apache-tomcat-8.5.29/bin/setclasspath.sh
apache-tomcat-8.5.29/bin/shutdown.sh
......
```

And a new directory must be created called **apache-tomcat-8.5.29**, now you only have to type the following command:

cd apache-tomcat-8.5.29

if you need to list it, then execute this

ls -l

Answer (score 0):

Before unpack with command tar try this:

```bash
sudo chmod 777 ./apache-tomcat-8.5.85
```

you need to perform this action before, because after download tar file is colored *red* and you need to make it *green*. You achive this result with `chmod 777` which change permission on the file.

Comment: I forgot.... after unpacking tomcat go to bin folder and run: ./startup.sh